# How to get VPN options in netwrking applet in Mint Linux 19?

Tags: networking, vpn, linux-mint, vpnc

I have just upgraded from Mint Linux 17.3 to Mint Linux 19. Now I am having trouble setting up a VPN the same way as in 17. In 17 I somehow had it that connecting to the VPN was an item on the menu when you clicked on the networking applet in the cinnamon desktop. Below is a pic of the networ applet in action (with no VPN options).

[image]

Now I can't seem to get this back again, can anyone advise how to do this, or if it is even possible?

Here's what the option looks like in Ubuntu (and what I had in Mint Linux 17):

[image]

In case it is relevant, I need to connect to a Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc).

I've tried installing all of the following packages, but still no menu item in the applet:

```
network-manager-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-pptp-gnome
network-manager-iodine
network-manager-iodine-gnome
network-manager-openconnect
network-manager-openconnect-gnome
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-strongswan
network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

If this is no longer possible, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I had to actually configure a VPN first (go to network connections and click on the + to add a vpn), then the option to connect appears in the network applet. It is just that the "Configure VPN" doesn't seem to be present in the Cinnamon version.